# What's the best way to publish a node package to PyPi?

Tags: python, node.js, npm, pypi

### Background

We're building an open source software project that runs on node.js, and is currently published on npm.

The software allows users to write markdown code files (in a directory) and have them compile into a web app.

However, **many of our users are not familiar with the Node.js toolchain** when they first encounter our project (they don't have node, npm etc). And installing them for the first time, in order to use our product can be pretty off-putting.

However, they **do** typically use Python.

### Question

Would love to be able to publish the package on PyPI, so that `pip install our-project` "just works".

Is this possible? What would be the best way to go about this?

### What does a users' project look like post install (simplified):

```
project-dir/
|- package.json
|- node-modules/
|  `- <the packages to run the project, inc our packages & deps>
|- pages/
|  |- user-markdown.md
|  `- user-markdown2.md
`- dev/
   `- <compiled pages populated here during runtime>
```

### Thoughts

I guess the package would have to (but I might be wrong)

1. Check if node is installed. If not, install it
2. Check if npm is installed. If not, install it
3. Install our npm packages

Comment: pip = python, js = npm. Dont start mixing things. Installing npm/node is like running 1 command or the UI guided windows installer. Wheres the problem? Write markdown but cant install software... Sounds like a xy problem. [copy & paste](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) or write a proper installation guide. Also this question is offtopic. Complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why not try to compile your NodeJS app to a native binary so that npm isn't needed? Or package your app with its own node runtime?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/cmake/ for an example of non-Python toolchain installable by `pip`. https://pypi.org/project/nodejs-bin/ — the very Nodejs.

Comment: @Marc. I take your point, but almost *every* user I've spoken to references trouble installing. Some cannot use npm due to company policies that struggle to connect to the registry. Some have an old version of node but don't realize it. It's just detrimental to the "first 10 mins experience"

Comment: @aemw How is any of this your problem? Customs want to use your software? They need to fullfill the requirements. Why do you make their problems your problems? Write a detail installation guide and everything else is not your problem.

Comment: @Marc we're an early stage project trying to help people to use our product. A frictionless (or as-little-friction-as-possible) install helps people actually try the product. Sure, some people get through the current install instructions. But we suspect a lot tear their hair out and give up before then. (Our target users are are not *primarily* software engineers.)